# I am trying to install React but it throws an error

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I run this command `npx create-next-app@latest` in my commannd prompt it will throw this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-22T16_21_08_061Z-debug-0.log
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: ...did you _read_ it? Do you think you do have a directory `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm`?